# Добавить нужные Checkbox в List

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Нужно придерживаться MVVM.
Есть Checkbox-ы(32шт), отмечаю нужные, пишу название группы, выбираю тип группы(3вида) и по нажатию на кнопку "Добавить", они должны упасть в List, который является одним из свойств группы. Понимаю, что надо добавить свойство bool во viewmodel и с ним работать, но не пойму как
Я сделал 2 модели: модель отдельного CheckBox и модель группы

```
public class CheckBoxModel : VM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private bool isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get => isChecked;
        set
        {
            isChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Модель группы:

```
public enum ActColor
{
    Red,
    Yellow,
    White
}

public class GroupOfCheckBox: VM
{
    private string name { get; set; }
    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ActColor actColor { get; set; }
    public ActColor ActColor
    {
        get => actColor;
        set
        {
            actColor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private List<CheckBoxModel> checkBoxList { get; set; }
    public List<CheckBoxModel> CheckBoxList
    {
        get => checkBoxList;
        set
        {
            checkBoxList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Вот MainViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public BindingList<CheckBoxModel> Checks { get; set; } = new BindingList<CheckBoxModel>();
    public CheckBoxModel SelectedCheck { get; set; }
    public ActColorModel Action { get; } = new ActColorModel { Red = true };

    public ObservableCollection<GroupOfCheckBox> GroupsOfCheck { get; set; }
    public GroupOfCheckBox SelectedGroup { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        for (var i = 1; i < 33; i++)
        {
            Checks.Add(new CheckBoxModel {Name = i.ToString()});
        }

        GroupsOfCheck = new ObservableCollection<GroupOfCheckBox>()
        {
            new GroupOfCheckBox() {Name = "1group", ActColor = ActColor.Red, CheckBoxList = new List<CheckBoxModel>{Checks[0], Checks[2], Checks[5]}},
            new GroupOfCheckBox() {Name = "2group", ActColor = ActColor.Yellow, CheckBoxList = new List<CheckBoxModel>{Checks[1], Checks[6], Checks[10]}}
        };


    }

    private RelayCommand addCommand;
    public RelayCommand AddCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return addCommand ??
                   (addCommand = new RelayCommand(obj =>
                   {
                       GroupOfCheckBox group = new GroupOfCheckBox{Name = Name, ActColor = Action.ActColor, CheckBoxList = new List<CheckBoxModel>{Checks[12]}};
                       GroupsOfCheck.Insert(0, group);

                   }));
        }
    }

}
```

Наверное, мне надо добавить еще во MainViewModel свойство (bool) IsChecked например, и создать какое-то событие обновление коллекции? 
Потом эта группа попадает в ListBox, и если я ее выбираю то CheckBox-ы которые есть в этой группе в List должны менять свой цвет, то есть выделяться...запутался как реализовать это((( подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: @АндрейNOP
А он и может быть в нескольких группах, то есть когда я выбрал несколько CheckBox-ов, добавил их в List в группу, и добавил группу, панель с CheckBox-ами обнулилась, в смысле снялись все IsChecked и я опять могу выбирать и добавлять в новую группу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я написал свой пример, но вы легко его адаптируете на свои классы. У меня вот такие VM-классы:

```
class GroupVm : Vm
{
    string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set => Set(ref name, value);
    }

    GroupType type;
    public GroupType Type
    {
        get => type;
        set => Set(ref type, value);
    }

    ObservableCollection<ItemVm> items;
    public ObservableCollection<ItemVm> Items
    {
        get => items;
        set => Set(ref items, value);
    }
}

enum GroupType
{
    Type1, Type2, Type3
}

class ItemVm : Vm
{
    string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set => Set(ref name, value);
    }
}
```

И главная VM (я создал группы для примера вручную, у вас они уже есть):

```
class MainVm : Vm
{
    public ObservableCollection<ItemVm> Items { get; }
    public ObservableCollection<GroupVm> Groups { get; }

    public MainVm()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemVm>
        {
            new ItemVm { Name = "Item 1" },
            new ItemVm { Name = "Item 2" },
            new ItemVm { Name = "Item 3" },
            new ItemVm { Name = "Item 4" },
            new ItemVm { Name = "Item 5" },
            new ItemVm { Name = "Item 6" },
            new ItemVm { Name = "Item 7" },
            new ItemVm { Name = "Item 8" },
            new ItemVm { Name = "Item 9" }
        };
        Groups = new ObservableCollection<GroupVm>
        {
            new GroupVm
            {
                Name = "Group 1",
                Type = GroupType.Type1,
                Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemVm>(new[] { Items[0], Items[1], Items[6] })
            },
            new GroupVm
            {
                Name = "Group 2",
                Type = GroupType.Type2,
                Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemVm>(new[] { Items[3], Items[8] })
            },
            new GroupVm
            {
                Name = "Group 3",
                Type = GroupType.Type3,
                Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemVm>(new[] { Items[2], Items[4], Items[7] })
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Далее нам понадобятся два конвертера (вместо конвертера типа группы в кисть можно использовать триггеры, но код будет более громоздкий, к тому же триггеры не удобно переиспользовать):

```
class GroupContainsConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var group = (GroupVm)values[0];
        var item = (ItemVm)values[1];
        return group.Items.Contains(item);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class GroupTypeToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var type = (GroupType)value;
        switch (type)
        {
            case GroupType.Type1:
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            case GroupType.Type2:
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
            case GroupType.Type3:
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Теперь разметка:

```
<Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <c:GroupContainsConverter x:Key="GroupContainsConverter"/>
        <c:GroupTypeToBrushConverter x:Key="GroupTypeToBrushConverter"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Value="True">
                        <DataTrigger.Binding>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource GroupContainsConverter}">
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}"
                                         Path="DataContext.Groups/"/>
                                <Binding/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                Value="{Binding DataContext.Groups/Type,
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},
                                    Converter={StaticResource GroupTypeToBrushConverter}}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>

    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

    <ListBox Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource GroupTypeToBrushConverter}}"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за помощь, сейчас буду разбираться)

Comment: Простите, не могу понять каким образом добавляются в группу объекты, не в программе, а что нажимать надо?)

Comment: Я показал лишь как раскрасить элементы, которые есть в выделенной группе. Вроде в этом ваш вопрос заключался?

Comment: А скажите, пожалуйста, если у меня CheckBox-ы, то также где-то надо привязку делать? Что-то не выходит у меня(

Comment: Абсолютно так же должно всё работать. У вас мой пример заработал? Попробуйте сначала его воспроизвести

Comment: Ваш пример работает конечно, попробовал, пытаюсь переделать свой, не работает. 
Выскакивает ошибка в конвертере GroupContainsConverter
в строке 
var item = (CheckBoxModel)values[1];
пишет нельзя преобразовать Test2.ViewModel.MainViewModel в Test2.Models.CheckBoxModel
это я что-то не то сделал в привязке? вроде как Вы все сделал

Comment: Там где MultiBinding в разметке ещё раз все внимательно проверьте

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78158/discussion-between--and--nop).